# Issues resetting variables in nested loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

Using a dataset, I am trying to analyze wave height. I'm picking a random x variable (measurement index) and running the y variable (wave height) through a while loop. The loop starts at the randomly assigned x, and adds 1 for each iteration. It ends when the y variable is below 1.75. I've assigned the number of x values it needs to go through to n, and print that out at the end.

I want to run the while loop a 100 times, adding the n-value for every run to a list.

I tried to make a for loop and put the while loop inside, like this:

```
x = (random.randint(1,2919))
n = 0
målinger=[]

for i in range(1,100):
    n = n
    while df._get_value(x,'BØLGEHØYDE') > 1.75:
        x = x+1
        n += 1
    målinger.append(n)

print(målinger)
```

But my output is just the first n-value printed 100 times. Very new to python and would appreciate the help.

Comment: What is `n = n` hoping to achieve?

Comment: @tadman Just making sure? :)

Comment: @Barmar Keeping it fresh! Like fluffing up a pillow.

Comment: @tadman when I print out the list, all 100 n values are the same. Trying to make the n-value back to zero at the start of each loop.

Comment: To set `n` back to 0 you would use `n = 0`, not `n = n`.

Comment: You're setting `n` to `n`, not `0`. If you want to reset to zero, `n = 0`.

Comment: What is `df._get_value()`? There's `df.get_value()`, but it has been deprecated, and you should be using `.at()` or `.iat()` instead.

Comment: There's only one `n` here; `n = n` does not use a global `n` to reset the value of a local `n`.